# Action when UIDatePicker started being used

Tags: ios, swift, uidatepicker

I want to trigger an action, as soon as the user starts to change the value of the UIDatePicker. My first instinct was to use the `datePickerEditingDidBegin` method but does not seem to do the job.

Comment: Hi, did you come out with any solution for triggering action on starting being used?

Answer (score 2):

Straight from the docs:

[UIDatePicker: Responding to User Interaction](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uidatepicker)

> Date pickers use the Target-Action design pattern to notify your app
> when the user changes the selected date. To be notified when the date
> picker’s value changes, register your action method with the
> valueChanged event. At runtime the date picker calls your methods in
> response to the user selecting a date or time.
>
> You connect a date
> picker to your action method using the addTarget(_:action:for:) method
> or by creating a connection in Interface Builder. The signature of an
> action method takes one of three forms, which are listed in Listing 1.
> Choose the form that provides the information that you need to respond
> to the value change in the date picker.
>
> Listing 1  Action methods for date pickers
>
> ```
> @IBAction func doSomething()
> @IBAction func doSomething(sender: UIDatePicker)
> @IBAction func doSomething(sender: UIDatePicker, forEvent event: UIEvent)
> ```

Connect your date pickers `valueChanged` send event to your `IBAction`

[image]

**Edit**:

Per the docs, `UIDatePicker` doesn't have any delegate methods, therefore something like `datePickerEditingDidBegin` wouldn't make any sense.

You have to use `UIControlEvent`.  If `valueChanged` doesn't suit your needs I would maybe suggest `touchDragInside`.

> An event where a finger is dragged inside the bounds of the control.

Other `UIControlEvent` descriptions located [here in the docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicontrolevents).

Comment: I know about valueChanged event, I am asking for event when the users **starts** to change the value of DatePicker but is not done yet.

Comment: Strangely, even `TouchDragInside` doesn't get kicked either. BTW, I was using the `EditingDidBegin` earlier, which is towards the top of your list.

Comment: You called also try overriding the `touchesBegan` method or adding a tap or pan gesture recognizer.

Answer (score 0):

This wasn't working for me too, I tried all UIEvent's like above. I was able to get this working by adding a pan gesture recognizer, conforming to the delegate and `shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith(: )` = true . See answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25719326/4970749