# UIPIckerView: how to define that selected item was selected again?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, user-interface, uipickerview

For example we have UIPickerView with 2 items: 'Item1', 'Item2'. User selected 'Item1'. This method is called

```
   public func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {}
```

But when user again selected that item 'Item1' then that method is not called.

Question: how to define that selected item ('Item1') was selected again on UIPickerView?

Comment: You can add a `UITapGestureRecognizer` [Check this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41427485/1714748) Regards

Comment: agscastaneda, thank you very much!!! it works for me!

Answer (score 0):

The method `titleForRow` only gets called to initialize titles/strings for the `pickerView`. I think you're looking for this method which gets called when user selects a row.

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
```

}

Comment: thanks for reply, Mochi. but didSelectRow is also not called if i select before selected item. so if i select Item1. it is called. again select Item1 it is not called. it will be called again if i select Item2

Comment: Okay, so you want the function called when item1 is selected again? Well.. just to clear things up, what do you want to happen when each item is selected?

Comment: Thank you, Mochi, for trying to help! User agscastaneda found the solution in the comment below my question.